# Adding null/Zero values to comma delimeted file using unix scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a requirment where, I get files from source with different number of delimeter data, i need to make them to one standard number of delimeted data.

source file1:

```
AA,BB,CC,0,0    
AC,BD,DB,1,0   
EE,ER,DR,0,0
```

What i want to do is appened an extra 3 zeros at the end for each row

```
AA,BB,CC,0,0,0,0,0  
AC,BD,DB,1,0,0,0,0  
EE,ER,DR,0,0,0,0,0
```

The source file always contains less number of column data . Can anyone help on this.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will add particular string after each line of mentioned file

```
sed '1,$ s/$/,0,0,0/' infile > outfile
```

Here is what I tried;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sed can do it in place with the -i flag

```
sed -i "s/$/,0,0,0/g" file
```